# Повторяющийся вызов функции в C++

Tags: c++

Всем привет!

Я делаю запросы по API и получаю от него данные, примерно вот так:

```
cpr::Get(cpr::Url{ URL })
```

(cpr библиотечка для запросов созданная на базе libcurl)

Проблема тут в том, что мне нужно делать запросы каждую минуту (или любой другой chrono интервал времени)

Как это сделать?

Стоит упомянуть, что потом новые данные я добавляю в

```
std::deque<std::string> myData;
```

и как то с ними работаю.

Также следует упомянуть, что эти данные потом будут отрисовываться в opengl (где есть loop)
В общем и целом ищу простой аналог setInterval как в JS, но для C++

Comment: Смотрите `<chrono>`, например, [`sleep_until()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until) или `sleep_for()`. Можете запускать в отдельном потоке, например...

Comment: Пример можно? Если запускать бесконечный while в отдельном треде и спать в нем, мне кажется современный C++ предоставляет куда более удобные средства для таких штук, может есть еще способы

Comment: @KarlosMargaritos вам в любом случае надо будет эти запросы делать в отдельном от отрисовки потоке, чтобы её не блокировать - так что "более удобные" средства реализации должны будут как минимум это обеспечивать, а какие это средства это уже дело вкуса, специфика вашего кода, проекта и т.д.

Comment: @ampawd Мне бы пример любого способа (например с помощью thread и async) чтобы я от него оттолкнулся

Comment: я примерно так делал. Использовал qt ( не чисто для этих целей конечно же) просто унаследовался от qthread и переопределил метод ран и в нем вайл(1) написал с обработкой